# Formatting a string with named curly braces with *args raises key error

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I have this string: `my_str='a pi{ece} of t{ext}'`

and these args: `args=['ece', 'ext']`

When calling: `>>> my_str.format(*args)`

It gives me: `KeyError 'ece'`

Any help?

Comment: What were you expecting that to do? Why did you use named placeholders and pass positional arguments?

Comment: I'm forced to implement it that way. Both with *args and named placeholders

Comment: Not likely. If we had more context, we might be able to tell you what you should actually do.

Comment: this `print( my_str.format(**dict( zip(args,args))) )` will print what you want. Have fun figuring out why. the other one is simpler: `'a pi{} of t{}.format(*args)'`. Maybe this will help: [understanding-kwargs-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769403/understanding-kwargs-in-python) .. or this: [unpacking-argument-lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists)

Comment: The formatter accesses `args['ece']`. Try this yourself in the interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is fstring. Fstring was added to python 3.6.

```
hello = "Hello"
person = "Jimmy"

args = [hello, person]
greeting = f"{args[0]}, {args[1]}"
print(greeting)
```

If you really want to use .format()

```
hello = "Hello"
person = "Jimmy"

args = [hello, person]
greeting = "{}, {}".format(*args)
print(greeting)
```

or

```
hello = "Hello"
person = "Jimmy"

args = [hello, person]
greeting = "{first}, {second}".format(first=args[0], second=args[1])
print(greeting)
```

Please google fstring and .format()

*Fstring is generally faster*